# Deploy an editable CLI application python package in Docker

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile, setup.py

I am trying to deploy an editable CLI python package in the docker.

My package is successfully built in the docker and when I execute `docker run greet-docker greet --help` it shows the help message with the subcommand.

When I execute the `docker run greet-docker greet say sam` it should echo `Hi sam` but it shows the help message with the subcommand.

**What did I miss!!**

---

***My code***

```
├── tests
├── __init__
├── pyproject.toml
├── Dockerfile
├── requirements.py
├── setup.py
└── src
     ├── __init__.py
     └── greetings.py
```

**greetings.py**

```
@click.group()
def main():
    pass

@click.command()
@click.argument('name')
def say(name):
    print(f'Hi {name}')
    
main.add_command(say)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**setup.py**

```
package_dir={"": "src"},
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(where="src"),
    python_requires=">=3.6",
    include_package_data=True,
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'greet= greetings:main'
        ]
    }
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6
RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
ENV PYTHONPATH=/app
RUN pip install --editable .
ENTRYPOINT [ "greet", "--help" ]
```

**requirements.txt**
`click`

Answer (score 0):

This took me almost a day to figure out. Remove the `ENTRYPOINT [ "greet", "--help" ]` from the docker file. Whatever command we run in the editable gets overwritten by the `ENTRYPOINT`.